# basic4android button click and Phone Call?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call, basic4android

I wish to  make  a button
inside the App
That  click  will  lead
To  call  specific  number , Open  The Phone  dialer
with  Specific Number 
Or  Open  SMS with  specific  Number.
How  can  i  do  ot ?

Answer (score 0):

Calling a phone number is done with [PhoneCalls](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/phone.html#phonecalls).
Sending Sms is done with [PhoneSms](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/phone.html#phonesms).

Comment: ThanksWould  you  be  kind  enoufg to  show  me  Short  Code ?

Comment: OK   DID  it  with  phone  Lib